# How to Get the Current Page's URL into Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible to get page URL into flash ?

Without using `ExternalInteface.call('window.location')`

`trace(this.loaderInfo.url)` simply return URL from where flash was loaded.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with ExternalInterface.call()?

Comment: We are writing widget and we are going to provide this widget for customer and distribute it with advertizing systems. To use ExternalInterface out customers should use allowScriptAccess and sometimes it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it to `FlashVars` param in the HTML embed code.

To do this, add the following JS:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var page_url = document.location.href;
</script>
```

Then pass that variable to Flash:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    AC_FL_RunContent( 
        'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0',
        'pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash',
        'width','550',
        'height','440',
        'src','myswffile',
        'quality','high',
        'movie','myswffile', 
        'flashvars', page_url
    ); 
</script>
```

**Note:** the code above assumes you're using `AC_RunActiveContent.js` javascript solution provided by Adobe.

Comment: We can't do it, we just give our customers swf widget and have to be sure, that it is able to get URL. Without allowscriptaccess and some extra-params. We do not know how customer will place widgets on their sites

Comment: So then make it a JS widget, paste a small script tag. Then dynamically load AC_RunActiveContent.js or swfobject or static embed (document.write), and pass the document.location.href as a flashvar.

Comment: of course i know, that i can make JS widget and get/pass any param i want. I'm asking about pure flash solution

Comment: AFAIK, unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this purely in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for posting the answer for two year old question, even though I hope it may be useful for some one

```
var bm:IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
bm.init();
trace(bm.url);
```

Comment: I could not understand.... are you asking is it can be used in flex? if so answer is it can be used in flex

Comment: I meant it can be used only in flex... & the question doesn't seem to be using flex.